# Could someone give me a light on a question of recursion with strings?

Tags: python-3.x, string, recursion

*Write a recursive function that takes a string and counts how many "A's" appear in it. Create the program that calls the function and prints the response.*

my code done in two ways are giving error in something that doesn't make sense to me..

```
def letter(x):
    qnt = 0
    if x[0] == "A":
        qnt = 1
    else:
        qnt = 0

    return letter(x[1:]) + qnt

x = str(input("Enter a word: ")).upper()
print(letter(x))
```

ou dessa outra forma

```
def letter(x):
    if x[0] == "A":
        return 1 + letter(x[1:]) 
    else:
        return 0 + letter(x[1:])

x = str(input("Enter a word: ")).upper()
print(letter(x))
```

it is giving this error:

```
Enter a word: agradable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\wilia\Downloads\atividades\atbRecQ3.py", line 28, in <module>
    print(letter(x))
  File "C:\Users\wilia\Downloads\atividades\atbRecQ3.py", line 25, in letter
    return letter(x[1:]) + qnt
  File "C:\Users\wilia\Downloads\atividades\atbRecQ3.py", line 25, in letter
    return letter(x[1:]) + qnt
  File "C:\Users\wilia\Downloads\atividades\atbRecQ3.py", line 25, in letter
    return letter(x[1:]) + qnt
  [Previous line repeated 6 more times]
  File "C:\Users\wilia\Downloads\atividades\atbRecQ3.py", line 20, in letter
    if x[0] == "A":
IndexError: string index out of range
```

and it should just add up how many times the string "A" existed in the program during the recursion.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please formulate your question in English? Thanks :)

Comment: ok, I already modified

Comment: `x[1:]` makes your string shorter each time. Eventually it's completely empty so you get this error. You need to have base case handling so there's no attempt to recurse on an empty string.